# Generate vibration and sense with the same piezo

Tags: esp8266, accelerometer, piezo, vibration

I would like to build a sensor that generates some vibration on a material and then sense the vibration of the material. The simplest approach seems like using a piezo transducer. Ideally in combination with an esp8266.

Is this possible or would I need to have separate sounding and sensing elements?

Comment: From the description so far, we can't rule out that it's possible. But the details matter.

Comment: What type of details do you think? I'm hoping to just to a quick buzz, then flip over to sensing measure the response.